# Is it possible to link a visual studio C++ project to a GUI project in C++ to avoid code replication?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio for a purpose but I want to create a GUI that uses parts of that C++ project but I don't want to replicate code.

I found two possible technologies: Windows Desktop Wizard and `wxWidgets`. Is it possible to do that link? Any advice? (It doesn't need to be one of those technologies - I just want to reuse the code.)

If I modify the C++ project, I will also need to do in my GUI project on every change and that is not what I want.

**Full Example:**

[Project Solution 1 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0jVX.png)

This is a Visual Studio 2010 project with a class with some methods (`Calculator` project).

[Project Solution 2 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbS3X.png)

This is a Visual Studio 2019 solution with 2 projects. The project `wxWidgetsApp` is my GUI application. The project `SumConsoleApp` is a Console app that uses a method from the Visual Studio 2010 project. In the `wxWidgetsApp` project, I want to call the same Console app to run in the background of my GUI (That part I didn't start yet).

I'm getting some error when I compile the `SumConsoleApp` which contains an instance of a class from the Visual Studio 2010 project (`Calculator`) as can be seen below.

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbspm.png)

The Calculator project runs normally when executed separated. Also the GUI project but without calling any external method.

On my `SumConsoleApp` project, I added the `Calculator` project in the *Additional Include Directories*.

All those things I'm trying to do are possible or they are not compatible?

Comment: Turn the project into a library and link that in your GUI application

Comment: *but I don't want to replicate code* -- Why would GUI code replicate non-GUI code?  Just have the GUI call the functions in your existing library.   You can do more research on this by doing a web search on *Model-View-Architecture*.

Comment: Is your existing (non-GUI) project a command line project?  What's best is to separate out all the common code and put it in a C++ library.  Then have your command line project IMPORT it, and your GUI code  IMPORT it also.  Think of how the MSVCRT library is imported.  It's not GUI.  It's not a command line.  It's a library, imported by either/both.

Comment: Thank guys, I will have a look and I will be back if that works.